# Set an image to many UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Say I have 60-70 UIImageViews and I want to dynamically load the same image into all of them at the same time (so to speak).

For example, if I were working on a web page with 60-70 divs and I wanted to give them all a background image I would give them all a class of `myDivs` and call `$('.myDivs').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');

I know how to set a UIImageView's image but is there an easy way to set a bunch at once in Objective C?

I did try searching but I was flooded with a ton of stuff that is really unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you wish to display the imageView(s).
If you are using a UITableView or a UICollectionView, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you can dynamically update an imageView placed in a cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    [self setCell:cell forIndexPAth:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)setCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPAth:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

    // 5. add picture with AFNetworking
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com/profileImageLocation"]];
    [cell.profileImage setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                        placeholderImage:nil
                                                 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                                     weakCell.profileImage
                                                     .image = image;

                                                 } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"bad url? %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
                                                 }];
}
```

Another option will be using a for loop like this:

```
- (void)addImagesToAllMyImageViews:(NSArray *)images
{
    for (id obj in images) {

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)obj;

            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? is there no easier way to just set the image property of a group of UIImageViews at once? I mean I get what's going on in the above but this is almost as much code as doing imageView1.image=myImage 60 times. (not really but close...)

Comment: Well, you did not specify how you wish to display the images, and when displaying them in a UITableView, this is how you would fetch an image from the web.
If you only put the images in an array, the you can do for(UIImageView *image in myImagesArray) { 
   image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}

Comment: Sorry, dont mean to sound ungrateful, just trying to get my head around the verbose nature of C

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do with tag property, select all ImageView and give them a teg like 777 and

```
for(id* subview in self.view.subview) {
   if([subview isKindaOfclass:[UIImageView class]] && (subview.tag == 777)) {
      UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)subview;
      imageVIew.image = youImage;
   }
 }
```

hope this helps you

Comment: is  `self.view.subview` supposed to be `self.view.subviews`  with an s? xcode throws a warning and suggests I change it but if I do I get the warning "Selector element type '__strong id* is not a valid object"

Comment: Yes,     self.view.subviews